# How can I change the appearance of axis labels in plot from ggpredict?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, axis-labels, aesthetics

I am creating a plot using ggpredict and would like to alter the notation used for the y-axis labels (they are displayed using exponential+00 notation - it looks ugly).

The code I am using looks like this:

```
Model <- glm(Proportion ~ poly(Year,2) * Area, data=data, family="quasibinomial)
predModel <- ggpredict(Model, terma="Year [all]", "Area")
plot(predModel, rawdata=TRUE) + labs(x="Year", y="Proportion, title="")
```

How can I change the appearance of the y-axis labels (picture of chart attached)?

[image]

Comment: You can try to adjust the labels via e.g. `+ scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())`

Comment: @stefan many thanks - did the job perfectly!